# How to make elements appear only when button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get answer to display when I press the Show Button but I can't get it to work. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong. I can get the first part to work where I generate a random integer. But the second part does not execute ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77mm2vbw/1/#&togetherjs=ieDMSJUyGL)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <button class="button" onclick="disp()">Generate</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="show_ans()">Show</button>

    <script>
        function disp() {
            var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 51) + 1);
            var j = 2 * i;
            document.getElementById("Goal").innerHTML = [i];

            function show_ans() {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = [j];
            }
        }
    </script>

    <p> Random Integer:
        <span id="Goal"></span>
    </p>

    <p> Computed Answer:
        <span id="answer"></span>
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Move your show_ans function outside of the disp function and define j outside of both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show_ans` only exists within the scope of the `disp` function, so anything outside that scope (such as the rest of the page) can't invoke it.

Move it outside that function:

```
function disp() {
    //...
}
function show_ans() {
    //...
}
```

Of course, since `show_ans` also relies on `j`, that too will need to exist in a scope where both functions can access it:

```
var j;
function disp() {
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 51) + 1);
    j = 2 * i;
    document.getElementById("Goal").innerHTML = [i];
}
function show_ans() {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = [j];
}
```